# CodeIgniter - Editing Output Buffer before sent to browser?

Tags: php, codeigniter, buffer, output-buffering

I'm researching the PHP framework [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/).  I need some help regarding editing the output before it's flushed to the user.

Usually in PHP, you can just use `ob_start();` and then `ob_get_clean();` to retrieve the contents.

While reading the CodeIgniter documentation, though, they say all output is already buffered.

Has anybody experience with unintentionally starting a second `ob_start()` ?  Alternatively, can anyone talk about the CodeIgniter output buffering so I may edit it?

Comment: in php you can have more than one buffer at the same time. starting a second buffer, then outputting the content would put that output into code igniters original buffer. basically code igniters buffer should not affect yours. chances are that you would not want to edit output buffers however since that is slow. better would be to edit content before it is stored on your server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know it's handled automatically by CodeIgniter, unless you manually specify the output methods yourself. See: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#output

(also congrats on deciding to use CodeIgniter, I can't get enough of this framework!)

Comment: The link you provided (Linking to the output feature) gives me the opportunity to edit the output before it's sent.  That's what I want!  Sweet!  Thank you very much!

Comment: the link is invalid for now

Comment: @AhmadAzwarAnas yeah seems EllisLab decided to change the URL without setting up any redirects. Bad practice! Updated my answer to the new URL now.